# Url query string values corrupt after being sent in email

Tags: email, html-email, nodemailer, url-parameters, spam-prevention

We send e-mail to our users containing URLs with a limited time access token encoded in base64 included via query string. In a small number of cases we are seeing users invoke our site with a different URL than expected. Specifically the values of query string parameters have been altered.

Here is an example of a URL (token is expired by now):

```
https://example.com?access_token=flWucTdvBvWFHmV4AvVfVaE8dDV9VxcKIDW2.flWjbJDvBvWvMwCxLGB5MF35BJMzYGFkMJVgBGt6ZD35ZmMxLGdkAEZkLGFvYDWyfUBvBwF5ZGZ8BGHlZEZfVzyueDV9ZGLkZwd7AGLjZa3.4WjeBK_dZdtCWk9DeTvDCFhyF6Wkf5BAKdVc1caihkF3xy84M2_EfYEvHMxmyYbgFFjh_K8c42wZJZmWBh84E_ee5TxWyaA_Gbg1TuIuetii4kAa6dfYwTthkFDwbD8W6hV1TAjTGfkDZ35CE-E-HIyGeEj2EJwvtKFzUbLcxcWCZhh-9ilffcfaEeKMFF4Me7ebatcfAkxkeFy7yAvi8etAeMD69BAuxMlb0T2TCfDtUKTazCaFd0t32XwAe61jFuMFaC6dvJ9ELGKLch8YJ8IYIc3AJeC4v4WEHe8wWMVMgmaLKAfvCX--mKBYaxh-ebwKLjdwY3Ke_c1yA2IuBYb8vF9_XFvDvIUFgBM8zeCCH952UvZ6V-BlBev9aK30iLblCXw4F7J0a-_c3YFbFlkfI7eFT4A2bg4DkHuiEEE21DMd5aejueXMdAgX0ehdBMZcj66DTcUD7CJje5cBvZzMxFC8EedE2e66ktFe8Exl8b1d_VYCiEfadBbycheLb5zvk-EzF1CWMbeEAAekAcLBWCEFVAjT6HX3IEZB_YetX80zEKa7VUMvTeFdeXzBE0L-vBDeVb1cEFh2aahccEjIcuAlGLAdagEDGbdt9cgbJ2C6HI92iM9ewB2t4xbbeeZFFVBGUfcKDy7aDyi03_Dw9jLLAFCyDCFj127_U4Z&expires_at=4946228536333
```

The example is very close to being valid: protocol, host and path are untouched, query string parameter names are correct and the length and type of parameter values is also close to the expected. The value of `expiry_at` should have been something close to `1613995200000`. If you shift all digits individually by 3 you get a value which is likely the original value.

The mails are sent using Nodemailer SMTP transport through SendGrid service. URLs are put together using `URLSearchParams` from Node.js. I'm reluctant to believe invalid URLs are sent from our systems, since more than 99% of users don't experience this issue. But I have no logging in sufficient detail to know for sure.

I don't have access to detailed information about network or mail filters at my users but I have seen users at the same company with and without the issue. In case this could be caused by some kind of encoding header mismatch, I've included a full example of raw headers and content from one of our e-mails:

```
Delivered-To: recipient@qvest.io
Received: by 2002:ac0:b64a:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id n10csp3067913ime;
        Mon, 8 Feb 2021 06:00:04 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJzmj9vRTtmN1IvVePlQBoEcReWgLQ0PonOzbLDHRnRc8DxWpGSKidkZ3OZPE6pAMBVTnEbu
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6e02:1b84:: with SMTP id h4mr15215295ili.196.1612792804205;
        Mon, 08 Feb 2021 06:00:04 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1612792804; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=o6BmAjDW2hu85OH++kbsbsOI77j4muGr6xny8LN4LS0QawzIgSCMrEMMFjWyZKiXwg
         pJNiyxIKBEP4hfWRBB4aDGNjAi6LROvCYX9mTZG8f5Yx5kd9U8gh5dhDLWQPTxh8Ix1h
         CW7Aan0v7E3TzHDTDV/HmmOqY6cbx+d8QZujuswankoPdqSIOkGPp7FlaO617C82z5Ce
         HIlTmKPXFngSkVW98UxtnGtvAjWuwpcMqOkIOHLJspfW183lDHBfg6ZOqQrWIfdGvet3
         Wr9kgvABU88bjqa41/LonF28jm88n4nI/5QYJVQGmQV7ELNVbWFZGaeO1m+J+ellFZ9h
         FHwA==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=list-unsubscribe:to:reply-to:mime-version:date
         :content-transfer-encoding:message-id:subject:from:dkim-signature;
        bh=QQMlgBEIEaxfQJ5P0N6Esf+zceZ2+qccFfw1P3Vcra0=;
        b=IOj2OtO9nFaNkW8JelpoEe9NHJEBIZnKn2HOqEbE9D95YwH0VqPzQn0dScsZJs6YCf
         aj8gbOzAj2m68GSBMtPN+9YbauZR+1Ygo+qxSGzjtngk71e+oGcfNJuoxQNS3qWJ4I8y
         O44MEFNZx/yIRsl8Sj1PMwkOgyi1NLLJGoRSLv2TGgDxfJXsqj/5IiDlhBESy0ONDuL1
         ZWz0Revg4BpcJ3dI0eqf0ljtiUQSAyn1fFi/+JHUBM5/oXqmW0LL1QRHxZte7d11NW8t
         Rs2K0RpuFMdZFzf/vhE5qvCxtGJokqQoOwWH7zfyPka+2CMaH3VV/DpMRL/txrp89yH2
         qy+g==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@qvest.io header.s=s1 header.b=LnUXPA7s;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io designates 168.245.121.57 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io";
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=qvest.io
Return-Path: <bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io>
Received: from o1.notify.qvest.io (o1.notify.qvest.io. [168.245.121.57])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id o9si15771544ilu.103.2021.02.08.06.00.03
        for <recipient@qvest.io>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Mon, 08 Feb 2021 06:00:04 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io designates 168.245.121.57 as permitted sender) client-ip=168.245.121.57;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@qvest.io header.s=s1 header.b=LnUXPA7s;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io designates 168.245.121.57 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom="bounces+6645413-7961-recipient=qvest.io@em9402.qvest.io";
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=qvest.io
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=qvest.io; h=content-type:from:subject:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version: reply-to:to:list-unsubscribe; s=s1; bh=QQMlgBEIEaxfQJ5P0N6Esf+zceZ2+qccFfw1P3Vcra0=; b=LnUXPA7swjX2NjzJ2TvETSJY5VT80AbEjWSwNcMYGw4MkfSYzVcaRAFwpmyp1G2scMg0 /OFqLVBN86MCPcybH+vVREbdOGcPEMIxaS5nAHMMwDCsXJE8IUe4+CiKwHXM9zMd676d+D ymYO442JwLoOBz22iAFyRjX56z8Sw4HiA=
Received: by filterdrecv-p3mdw1-689c95dc44-9222s with SMTP id filterdrecv-p3mdw1-689c95dc44-9222s-20-602143E2-164
        2021-02-08 14:00:02.769325447 +0000 UTC m=+418785.634806042
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (unknown) by ismtpd0004p1lon1.sendgrid.net (SG) with ESMTP id wSs4J7aLQt-9UHbZ3GKoTg for <recipient@qvest.io>; Mon, 08 Feb 2021 14:00:02.608 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: "Qvest" <noreply@qvest.io>
Subject: Subject
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2021 14:00:02 +0000 (UTC)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Reply-To: "Qvest Support" <support@qvest.io>
To: Recipient <recipient@qvest.io>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset=3D"UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv=3D"x-ua-compatible" content=3D"ie=3Dedge">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=
=3D1">
</head>

<body>
<a href=
=3D"https://example.com?access_token&#x3D;eyJhbGciOiJSUz=
I1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwaWQiOiI5ZDE0MTc5Ni02YTEyLTExZWItOWY4YS01N2IyN2U2=
NTczMGIiLCJleHAiOjE2MTQwMDI0MDMsImlhdCI6MTYxMjc5MjgwMn0.t7km4fdjgRHvggNcPFi=
mZZzwFsvhvBaUlD2q0MEvKRtEOSDcs6oZ_vt2A9A0qNKk_hhLCFhZbaXaRjexsr4b8-XCEiRrPE=
atLSq0EcE9P3W2kqyut4_8_2Apvm03fiR6gQkfQXwosfHVPT3aULtQ_xUyRNydG10ChTM-hfYtD=
yvavPivP9gpN82pSzMk4DBR_HztHEFDGbbgDnzQ6d_j4kj8bcQXGdWTlw_eefA7H9i7WqvD_6pK=
LsaEjODCt7Ys4UIRBKvhulFfatdQXTOnXvMoIUIjavHHbDrTaZKr53P5DHRsZXPhDGMXjxYfbhk=
GmoFALLGgwxmwNpkVMJaDLH1EyQ_avo9TXjtEcoPVXd3vWddoYEpX5QcOrK1O1NYCS8A_KQiRcZ=
ZMAujzRs65SJ--NQUPKr1_jwfcRgcUwB-10nJjet1G0U2uajDktlc5uqE9aqW7Mnhxn9pJ8WqUE=
eIrnViqCYfAAyAZRMqneJi9WOmaYm4DohkZHQ0er6Z4gsRDIV8Dwy4vFCwbrNvw2PWuVTh7R9U8=
Nu784UOFyzDUw2HRDEJVqXYp-4VgmSlF5GG8h9TFVTrSycA7hr2K46RXidGIHLbeHp6twiN7_pO=
7uRqAzrGBcaXb4Xf0HEp1TpHOFK3AJyMHdda_lGB_X_Ht2LBWT4mPaN7OJBi1-xg&amp;expire=
s_at&#x3D;1614002403000">this link</a>

</html>
```

Comment: My guess would be that they are using a broken email client; unfortunately, it's not hard to find clients which do stupid things with URLs, and conversely, it's hard to find clients which handle email entirely correctly. Is there any way you could make the URLs themselves more robust, i.e. a lot shorter, and without any characters which need to be escaped for various reasons?

Comment: Some firms have security software that changes links, like URLDefense. Could it be that?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your comment. We could definitely make them shorter. As for escaping, we are already sticking to a base64 and as far as I can tell the only thing that is being escaped are characters needed to define the URL query string itself and I won't be able to get rid of those. They also seem to be unaffected by the issue.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you. I did not know URLDefense and it is useful for me to get more familiar with what kind of security software we might run into. I am attempting to get more details from our customers but it is hard when I don't know exactly what to ask for and many of the customers don't even know themselves what exactly their security software is doing for them..

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well. In the web server logs, about half the email unsubscribe requests have corrupted query parameter values (the parameter keys are unchanged). Each letter in the parameter values has been replaced with a different letter in a nearly-consistent, one-for-one way. Additionally, the IP addresses that are making these requests all come from MICROSOFT-CORP-MSN-AS-BLOCK. I don't know if these requests are from actual users trying to unsubscribe, or if they're an automatic mechanism for verifying the legitimacy of the links.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing: one-for-one replacement of URL parameters and what seems to be an automatic mechanism for verifying the legitimacy of links.  I believe it is automatic because the unsubscribe request usually comes within seconds or minutes after the email is sent, and this happens constantly -- it is not likely that the emails are being opened and clicked on so rapidly, so it must be a link checker.  Because of learning this now I need to disregard these "unsubscribe requests" for now, and make a system w/o parameters). @MoxleyStratton Did you ever gain more info about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It's users that have Microsoft Advanced Threat Protection enabled on their account or domain.

I was having the exact same problem with a base64-encoded JSON string being corrupted in the same way, check out [my investigation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72644834/microsoft-email-advanced-threat-protection-corrupting-base64-path-in-url), I have collected a bit more information that correlates with yours.

I've send 2 emails to Microsoft's NOC/Abuse contacts, no response yet.

Regarding the other answers:

- Broken Email client and/or bad header encoding explanations are very unlikely, because these requests are coming exclusively from Microsoft-owned IP addresses. I've collated and verified (I have a list of 6,924 subnets and 11,043 IP addresses of visits.

In addition, per my analytics tracking, these sessions do not have any human activity associated with them after the visit. I.e. I have an error page that invites them to send me a message for support, no one ever has (out of 11000+ requests), however with other issues I do get support requests from users.